# Jackson missing colon and value in JSON after key

Tags: jackson

I'm [trying to chase a bug](https://bugs.opendaylight.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5980) where Jackson serializes some class ApiDeclaration { String apiVersion ... private JSONObject models } as {"apiVersion":"1.0.0",  ..., "models"}" - note that "models" is a JSON key with the ':' and value missing!

This is in app where this worked before, and it's possible that a recent upgrade from Jackson 2.3.2 -> 2.7.4 may have broken this for us.

Does application code have to something particular for a "mixed bean" (i.e. a static Java class with some 'normal' fields but also a JSONObject) ?